# iOS: How to get access to a variable used in the root view controller when I'm 2 levels down in the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, oop, model-view-controller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to build an app that sends and HTTP request and some part of this request is stored in an object in the root view controller. How can I get access to this object once I'm two levels down in the navigation stack? Global variables declared in the App Delegate? I'm trying to keep MVC rules in place.

Comment: you can create a Singleton `Store` class and store your global data in there, this is known as the MVCS (S for store) model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing such information in View Controllers isn't a good idea, imo. Better, create a class that manages your HTTP request and call to it from anywhere you want (singleton, or just pass an instance)